# back to home automatically every 30 seconds

Tags: jquery

How I can make the site back to home automatically every 30 seconds?

I am designing a site that will be displayed in the lobby of a hospital, this site operate on a touch screen, for general information. We need to return to the home site automatically after a person stops using it.

Comment: How do you plan to define the 'idle' time? Are you measuring keypresses, page-loads, mouse/cursor movements..?

Comment: What if a user takes longer than 30 seconds to simply read something on the page?  Too bad, start over?

Answer (score 4):

Check out this nice jQuery [**idletimer**](http://paulirish.com/2009/jquery-idletimer-plugin/) plugin from Paul Irish and the [**demo here**](http://paulirish.com/demo/idle-timer)

Basically it will trigger a callback function after specified idle time and inside which you can forward it back to home page.

Usage:

```
// idleTimer() takes an optional argument that defines the idle timeout
// timeout is in milliseconds; defaults to 30000
$.idleTimer(10000);

$(document).bind("idle.idleTimer", function(){
 // function you want to fire when the user goes idle
});     

$(document).bind("active.idleTimer", function(){
 // function you want to fire when the user becomes active again
});

// pass the string 'destroy' to stop the timer
$.idleTimer('destroy');
```

**Please Note the Event covered:** 'mousemove keydown DOMMouseScroll mousewheel mousedown touchstart touchmove' [From source code](https://github.com/paulirish/jquery-idletimer/blob/master/jquery.idle-timer.js#L100)

Answer (score 0):

I found this code example to be the most useful.

http://www.bedroomlan.org/coding/detecting-%E2%80%98idle%E2%80%99-and-%E2%80%98away%E2%80%99-timeouts-javascript

```
setIdleTimeout(30000); // 30 seconds
document.onIdle = function() {window.location = 'URL to navigate to'}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a touch screen, just clicks enough to break idle time, so

```
var idle, isIdle;
function createIdle() {
idle = window.setTimeout("alert('hey where are you?')",5000);
}

$("*").click(function(){ 
    clearTimeout(idle);
    createIdle();
});
createIdle();​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ocanal/CEEuA/1/

Answer (score -1):

You can also do this with just the html markup using the [refresh meta tag](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/document/index_tagsupp_4.html) and avoid using javascript all together:

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="30; url=http://www.yourdomain.com/">
```

This assumes that every action that the user takes will navigate away from the current page and to a new page.  If that is the case, then by adding this to the head of each page, the browser will redirect back to the index any time the user does not navigate to another page in less than 30 seconds.

Comment: Then after 30 seconds (even while somebody is still using the kiosk) it dumps them back home.

Comment: @Sparky672, that depends on the way the kiosk application is designed. If it uses a touch screen then it probably only captures clicks and such kiosks are frequently constructed from static html files. In that senario this technique would work fine. You are right that if there are in-page interactions then a javascript solution would be required.

Comment: I would love if people could explain why they are down voting this answer. It does not assume anything but offers a legitimate solution for some scenarios where I believe javascript is not the best answer.

Comment: I was tempted to down-vote but I didn't.  However, I still don't understand your explanation.  AFAIK, this will dump a user back to home after 30 seconds regardless of his activity.

Comment: @Sparky672, it will dump him back to the home after 30 seconds of sitting on the same page. If he clicks on a link he gets 30 more seconds.

Comment: Exactly, whether he's interacting with that page or not, he's getting dumped back after 30 seconds... unless he clicks a link and goes to another page.

Comment: He said, that the kiosk uses a touch screen and "We need to return to the home site automatically after a person stops using it." If there is no mouse/keyboard then these types of applications frequently are designed to fill the page (no scrollbar) and have no in-page interactions, but are just hyperlinked html pages. In this scenario "stops using it" means not clicking on a link. That is the situation I'm covering here. If you have in page forms, scrollbars, or other interactive elements then this will not work as previously mentioned.

Answer (score -1):

I've used both a meta refresh

`<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="30;url=http://www.the-domain.com">`

and a delayed window.location

`window.setTimeout("location='http://www.the-domain.com'",30000);`

to do this.

Comment: -1: Avoid using string eval (including in `setTimeout`); use an anonymous function instead.